# How to write "Isaiah 41,10" in Hebrew?

Tags: number, hebrew, translation

I've already seen that someone wanted to know how to write Isaiah in Hebrew, but my question is mainly about the numbers, because I found just a few numbers, which can be written in Hebrew. I've already found the number 10, but how do you write the number 41?

Comment: I vote to close as off topic (Hebrew language questions are not in scope). See meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/162/759 and the FAQ.

Comment: @DoubleAA why targum-tranlation?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I guess because it wants us to translate 41 into Hebrew. You can change it if you want; it's going to be closed soon anyway.

Answer (score 2):

When writing Gematrias, you write as much as possible with the biggest numbers, then write the smaller and smaller numbers successively.

Two (or more) numbers one after another is just the sum of them together.

So 
מא - which is 40+1 = 41.

833 = תתלג
999 = תתקצט
1004 = תתרד

(400+400+200+4), unless you want to write an Aleph before for the thousands (א'ד)

Comment: It is pretty common to separate the two letters with double apostrophes: מ"א

Answer (score 1):

מא

mem aleph

mem = 40
aleph = 1

The numbers jump by 10 between 10 and 100. (then they jump by 100 until 400, taf)

yud = 10
caf=20
lamed=30
mem=40